# How to call function of another block Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to change the reference block of contact us link..I created all the phtml file and all.. 
Now in Phtml file when i am calling

```
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
```

I am getting number of links as 0..because it cant get the object of links.php.. 
I want to know how can I have reference object of contacts.phtml

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Hi you can do it by creating reference to that Block.Like

```
 $cpBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('your block class'); //ect Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
```

Than you can easily call every function of that class like `$cpBlock->getLinks();`.Other way is using XML block code.Add contact us xml reference just like user2338443 mentioned to your custom xml and than access functions of that block.

Comment: I tried this.
$tabLinks = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation');
$allLinks = $tabLinks->getLinks();
but return empty array.
Any help??

Comment: 'getBlockSingleton()' is not working, 'createBlock()' is working..I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

block to block calling

Also try call other block class method from current template block class.

```
$s = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('myproductfamily/family');
        print_r($s->getCollection($collectionId));exit;
```

where: myproductfamily = ModuleName

family = blockClass

Answer (score 2):

You can reference using a layout XML file.

for example:

```
<block type="{Here you can add reference}" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
```

Comment: I didnt get you
Actually what i want to do is to change the location of contact Us ..now i have hide the contact us from link.phtml..and also i have created new phtml ..but when i am doing this->getLinks() ..to get all the URL values i am getting NULL over there

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this. 
There are two syntax to call block method/function as below.

```
$_blockData = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('yourmodule/blockname')->getFunctionName();
```

or

```
$_blockData = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('yourmodule/blockname')->getFunctionName();
```